# Cannot build manual ref count CocoaPod

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, cocoapods

I have an iOS CocoaPod that is a couple of years old as a pod, and several years older than that as a reusable component.  Previously built with older versions of Xcode.  It was developed with and remains "manual reference counting".  I am now trying to import it into a "new" project (actually reconstructed from an old project and also manual reference counting), but I cannot get it to build.

As I said, the enclosing project is manual reference counting and compiles OK that way with no pods installed.  "Automatic Reference Counting" is set to "No" in "Build Settings".

However, *even though the exact same Build Settings "No" value is present in the pods project*, it always generates a compile script with `-fobjc-arc`, and calls to `retain` and `release` are flagged as errors.  (Eg, `error: 'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode`.)

The version of Xcode is 6.0.1.

The version of `pod` is 0.34.4 (installed fresh yesterday).

The podspec for the pod in question:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "libXXX"
  s.version      = "1.0"
  s.summary      = "Exchange library for XYZ."
  s.description  = "Static library pod for the XXX framework."
  s.homepage     = "http://example.com"
  s.license      = { :type => 'MIT', :text => 'Copyright 2012 XYZ' }
  s.author       = { "Bill Nye" => "bnye@example.com" }
  s.source       = { :git => 'https://code.example.com/ios/XXX.git', :tag => '1.0' }
  s.platform     = :ios
  s.source_files = 'StaticLib/Headers/*.h'
  s.preserve_paths = 'StaticLib/libXXX.a'
  s.library = 'XChangeA'
  s.xcconfig = { 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/libXXX/StaticLib' }    
  s.dependency 'libSignatureToken'
end
```

I tried adding `s.requires_arc = false` to the pod spec (and performing `pod update`), but nothing changed.  I also tried `s.compiler_flags = '-fno-objc-arc'`, with no success.

So, how do I convince Xcode to compile the pod with manual reference counting?

---

## Resolved

Apparently "unrelated" problems during `pod update` caused it to fail silently without configuring the compile mode info.  Running `pod update --verbose` repeatedly helped smoke out the problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `s.requires_arc = false`

This is documented [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#requires_arc). The default recently changed from `false` to `true`. Also this error should appear if you run `pod spec lint`.

Comment: Maybe you didn't notice, but I tried requires_arc = false

Comment: Ah yes I did miss that since it wasn't in the spec. If you can provide an example spec with this that doesn't work in a clean project please do and create [an issue](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods)